# Returning Akka.Future - Play Framework

Tags: playframework, akka

In the following piece of code, I'm trying to return an Async result which is an Akka.future in this case. When I tried to map the result for the method's response, I get a compile error that says

```
[error] Test.scala:180: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[String]]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
[error]         jsonResponse.map((s: String) => Ok(s))
```

Here is what I tried:

```
  def testAkka(jsonList: List[String]) = Action {
    Async {

      val ftrList: List[Future[String]] = jsonList.map((s: String) => Akka.future {returnSomeVal(s)} )

      val futureList: Future[List[String]] = Future.sequence(ftrList)

      val jsonResponse: Future[String] = futureList.map((f: List[String]) => f.mkString(","))

      Akka.future {
        jsonResponse.map((s: String) => Ok(s)) // Compiler complains here
        //Ok(jsonResponse)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What version of Play are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jsonResponse.flatMap, instead of map